# Use standard output as an input in awk

Tags: awk, stdout

I have a file that I cannot do any modification due to permission issues.

So I can only visualize the files with a tool and its view option which prints out its content to a standard output with 8 tab delimited columns :

```
foo-tool view file1.txt
ALICE  .  CANDY   1990  . 76 76 78
MARK   .  CARAMEL 1991  . 45 88 88
CLAIRE .  SALTY   XXX   . 77 82 12
```

I do have another file that I want to compare its `1st,6th and 7th` columns with the `1st,6th and 7th` columns of `file1.txt`, and add the `3rd and 4th` columns of `file1.txt` to `file2.txt` in case of any match in these columns.

```
file2.txt
ALICE  .  CANDY   1990  . 76 76 97
MARK   .  CARAMEL 1991  . 45 88 87
BLAINE .  SALTY   XXX   . 77 82 10
```

If I would be able to open `file1.txt` rather than only standard output, I would do :

```
awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1,$6,$7] = $0; next }($1,$6,$7) in a { print a[$1,$6,$7], $3, $4 }' file1.txt file2.txt
```

So the output would be :

```
ALICE  .  CANDY 1990  . 76 76 78 CANDY    1990
MARK   .  54    1991  . 45 88 88 CARAMEL  1991
```

But, since I cannot use the `standard output` of `file1.txt` as a file, I am stuck on how to proceed.
I tried to open it and direct its standard output but it did not work:

```
foo-tool view file1.txt | awk 'NR==FNR { a[$1,$6,$7] = $0; next }($1,$6,$7) in a { print a[$1,$6,$7], $3, $4 }' ARG[$1] file2.txt
```

How can I pass the standard output as a file input in awk as one of the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"`-`" (a dash) is a special filename that means standard input. This convention is used in many Unix tools, and especially `awk`

Your command line must then be:

```
$ foo-tool view file1.txt | awk '{ your_program }' - file2.txt
```

Alternatively, if your system supports it (Linux does), you can use the `/dev/stdin` file:

```
$ foo-tool view file1.txt | awk '{ your_program }' /dev/stdin file2.txt
```

You can also use "process substitution" if your shell supports it (bash, ksh and zsh do):

```
$ awk '{ your_program }' <(foo-tool view file1.txt) file2.txt
```

It may be useful if you have to process the output of several distinct commands, like:

```
$ awk '{ your_program }' <(foo-tool view file1.txt) <(foo-tool view file2.txt)
```